# html, в чем ошибка

Tags: html, img

Валидатор w3.org указывает на ошибки

```
 Line 76, Column 131: attributes construct error

…72.jpg" alt="Парус" title="Парус "width="171"/></a></div><div class="cena deg">
```

✉
    Error Line 76, Column 131: Couldn't find end of Start Tag img line 76

```
…72.jpg" alt="Парус" title="Парус "width="171"/></a></div><div class="cena deg">
```

✉
    Error Line 96, Column 143: attributes construct error

```
…" alt="Описание" title="Описание "width="171"/></a></div><div class="cena deg">
```

✉
    Error Line 96, Column 143: Couldn't find end of Start Tag img line 96

```
…" alt="Описание" title="Описание "width="171"/></a></div><div class="cena deg">
```

✉
    Error Line 116, Column 143: attributes construct error

```
…" alt="Описание" title="Описание "width="171"/></a></div><div class="cena deg">
```

✉
    Error Line 116, Column 143: Couldn't find end of Start Tag img line 116

```
…" alt="Описание" title="Описание "width="171"/></a></div><div class="cena deg">
```

и тычит все вот в эту строчку

```
<div class="desc">
<a href="preview.php?id=57">
<img src="img/izdelia/main_1440283311.jpg" alt="Описание" title="Описание "width="171"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробел не хотите поставить между `"` и `width`?

Comment: Спасибо, что то я пропустил этот момент :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в пробеле перед width.